# Best practice for storing and referencing DLL libraries?

Tags: dll, version-control

Often times a developer on my team will create a new Visual Studio project and reference a DLL somewhere on their local machine (e.g., C:\mydlls\homersimpson\test.dll).  Then, when I get the project from the source control repository, I cannot build the project because I do not have the referenced dll in the exact same location on my machine.

What is the best practice for storing and referencing shared libraries?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I typically create a lib folder in my project, where I put the referenced dll's.  Then I point the reference to the dll in the lib folder.  This way, every developer can build the project after retrieving from source control.

If it's a project that was built in house, you could also add that project to your solution.

Comment: This was my first thought, too.  The only drawback I see is that if you have a commonly used DLL it'll be in source control in multiple locations for each project that references it.

Comment: @vg1890: Multiple copies of the dll may be a benefit, it would allow each project to potentially use a different version of the dll

Comment: I recommend GAC alongside versioning. This way, by using a pre-built event you can install that DLL from the share repository into your GAC.

Comment: I think now is preferable to keep artifacts externally and including it at compile time using something like Artifactory, NuGet, Maven and so on.

Answer (score 3):

If the assembly is not in the GAC, create a directory called dependencies and add all assemblies there.  The folder and the assemblies are added to source control.  The rule is that given any project in source control, all that is required to build is to do a checkout and build the project (or run some tool that is also checked into the project).

If you add a folder to the solution and add the assemblies to the solution folder, this also provides a visual cue to the devs that indicates what external dependencies are present... all dependencies are in that directory.  Relative paths ensure that Visual Studio can locate the references without a problem.

For large solutions, with 20+ projects, this makes life much easier!

Answer (score 2):

Best practice I would expect would have Your SC repository include and enforce the relative locations of referenced objects for you (usually via a shared path), so you aren't dealing with this issue directly. The original developer should check in this information.

Comment: How not? Do you not include all linkable modules in SCC?

Comment: Right - "Go directly to dll-hell. Do not pass Go, ..."

Answer (score 1):

If you check in the actual DLLs into source control, then you can reference them by relative path and all developers will automatically get any dependencies when they next update the project.

Adding a DLL reference by full path would be a developer error just as adding a source file by full path would be an error.

Comment: Do you check in your binaries to your source code version control?

Comment: No, not my own binaries. I had assumed the original question was talking about some third party DLL which was not built with the project.

Comment: Ok that makes more sense. We do the same thing with third party libraries.

Answer (score 1):

**Rule of thumb**: If the project isn't a part of the solution, reference released dlls from a source controlled /binshare or /lib directory that is under your solution's source control tree. All external dependencies should have versioned DLLs that go in this /binshare directory.

I understand what your co-worker is doing in regards to convenience. However, that developer's approach is diametrically opposed to proper configuration/build management.

Example: If you use the MS Data Application Block as a dependency in your application, you should reference a properly released binary, instead of getting latest from MS's dev source trunk.

Comment: Is your first sentence written in English? :)  Maybe some commas or conjunctions would help me understand it?

Answer (score 1):

I think this approach is quite the opposite of what I would consider best practice.  I think it would be a much better approach to keep the third party binaries out of the source repository and reference them through something like a Maven repository in your build process.  Putting the dlls in the source repository unnecessarily bloats the contents of the repository and results in gets of projects taking considerably longer then necessary.  It also makes the independent management of the third party binaries' versions obfuscated by not referencing the version by name but rather implied by referencing the dll of a particular version stored in the projects lib folder.

Answer (score 1):

Why not set up a private NuGet-feed? This way, there is only a single copy of a dependency (the NuGet repository) and multiple projects can reference it. Multiple versions of the dependency can coexist, and each project can reference a different version, if necessary. Also, TFS Build can restore the packages at build time.

Configuring VS: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/package/nuget/consume